# C++ structs incrementing

Tags: c++, struct, increment

I'm fairly new to programming and mostly self taught and I don't know much about the jargon so I'm not sure about how to search for this and therefore haven't found an answer through just searching.  Onto the question

Is there anyway to increment a struct?  Like I would in for loops using an int.  I'm creating a simple program where I'd input multiple students and want to create multiple instances of structs that increment.  Example

```
struct student{
    string name;
    int id;
}x[i];
i++;
```

sorta like that.  Sorry if I'm a little confusing.  Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: are you asking if you can have an array of structs ? If so, sure you can.

Comment: I think he's asking to create multiple instances of student with a unique id.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I can't explain it easier.  But I want to use a struct kinda like an array like int num[10] where I can input 10 numbers by incrementing i.

Comment: "But I want to use a struct kinda like an array" - no, what you really want is an _array of_ the struct type.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is make a collection of `student` objects.

In C++, the `std::vector` class is generally the best choice for a collection type, and in your case as well.

---

**How to use a `vector`**

To use an `std::vector` you must first `#include` the `<vector>` header file. Then you can declare an `std::vector` object with the following syntax:

```
std::vector<T> name;
```

where `T` is the type of elements you want to store in the `vector`, and `name` is a name for the collection. In your case, you want the type to be `student`, and a good name for a collection containing students would be `students`, for example:

```
std::vector<student> students;
```

---

**Adding objects to the `vector`**

Now you can start adding `student` object to the `vector`. The `push_back()` function of the `vector` class can be used for this, like this:

```
students.push_back(foo);
```

where `foo` is a `student` variable you have created earlier.

---

**Accessing objects in the `vector`**

Now that you have added a `student` to the `vector`, you can access it with the `at` function:

```
students.at(0);
```

The above line will access the first object in the `vector`. The `at` function is also really useful if you accidentally try to access an object that's not in the `vector`, for example, you try to access the second object, which we haven't added yet:

```
students.at(1);
```

Because we only have one `student` stored in the `vector` so far, trying to access the second `student` with `at` will result in an **error**. Which is great! Now we know we did something wrong, and the error message will probably even tell us what we did wrong.

---

**About `vector` vs raw array**

A raw array like `int numbers[10]` will not tell us if we accidentally try to access over the end of the array like `int x = numbers[10]`. There will be no useful error messages to tell us were doing something wrong, the program will probably just silently continue execution and start behaving oddly. Which is what we as programmers don't want. Thus a `vector` is a superior alternative.

Note that with a `vector` you also don't have to specify a size, as with raw arrays. `vector`s will automatically grow as you add new objects to it, so you don't have to worry about adding too many.

Comment: You should put the better way first.

Comment: But if he use struct, perhaps he is in C, not C++

Comment: @Puppy I could, but I prefer to first answer the actual question, and then suggest improvements.

Comment: The question does not indicate any preference for abject stupidity. Also, since he tagged C++ and used std::string (apparently) then he is in C++.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin It's tagged C++.

Comment: Ho sorry i haven't seen It.

Comment: @Puppy I get your point, but putting the right way last doesn't mean undervaluing it since I'm explicitly stating it's the better way. The OP both learns the syntax for creating raw arrays of custom objects and also that there's a better way to do what they want.

Comment: Additionally `std::vector` even has an `operator[]` to access an element at a specific index (to state the similarity in syntax).

Comment: @zenith: It does explicitly undervalue it. People will not read all the post and they certainly won't understand it. You should not post terrible practices to people who clearly don't understand the very basics and then just disclaimer them.

Comment: @Puppy Okay that does make sense. I rewrote the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct student{
    student(){}
    student(int i;string n):id(i),name(n){//this is student constructor}
    string name;
    int id;
};
int numberOfStudents=10;
student arrayOfStudents[10];
for (int i=0;i<numberOfStudents;i++){
     arrayOfStudents[i]=student(i,"studentname");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying. In case you want to have an array of **static size** and want to increment over it's element, use this:

```
const unsigned int SIZE = 10;
struct student{
    string name;
    int id;
}x[SIZE];
```

and to iterate over it:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    somefunction(student[i]);
}
```

---

If you want to have a **dynamic amount** of elements, you could for example use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

```
std::vector < student > x;
x.push_back(student("John Doe", x.size() - 1));
```

Iterating over it works the same way as with arrays.

Comment: Yes, thank you this is it.  Worked perfectly for the static size but I'm not quite sure how to use the dynamic one yet, I'll have to read up.  I really didn't know how to explain it but I am glad you understood.

Answer (score -1):

You can use array of struct and traverse them, or use pointers to struct and increment the pointer to traverse.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct student{
    string name;
    int id;
};
int main()
{
    int noOfStudent;
    cout << "Enter number of student: ";
    cin >> noOfStudent;

    student *x = new student[noOfStudent];

    for ( int i = 0; i < noOfStudent; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter Student Name: ";
        cin >> x[i].name;
        cout << "Enter Student ID: ";
        cin >> x[i].id;
    }

    delete[] x;
    return 0;
}
```